# Stuggling to get arrows keys to work when passing through functions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, function, keyboard-events

So I'm trying to make a game for our final project (high school) and we've recently swaped over to the new Visual Basic 2010 from VB6. But my question today is, that whever I try to use the KeyDown event and call it from another procedure

```
KeyValue = _5x5_Board_KeyDown(KeyValue)
```

It is flagging it up as it doesn't contain the "sender" or "e" that is used for the event to activate. And if I enter those into the call for the program, It says they're not defined. But as far as I'm aware, they are system defined.

```
    Public Class _5x5_Board
Dim xpos As Integer
Dim ypos As Integer
Dim Tile(6, 6) As PictureBox
Dim KeyValue As Integer

Private Sub _5x5_Board_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object)
    'Test start position (center of the board)
    xpos = 3
    ypos = 3

    'Assisgning all of the picture boxes to the array
    'You can ignore this part...
    Tile(0, 1) = Tile0_1
    Tile(0, 2) = Tile0_2
    Tile(0, 3) = Tile0_3
    Tile(0, 4) = Tile0_4
    Tile(0, 5) = Tile0_5

    Tile(1, 0) = Tile1_0
    Tile(1, 1) = Tile1_1
    Tile(1, 2) = Tile1_2
    Tile(1, 3) = Tile1_3
    Tile(1, 4) = Tile1_4
    Tile(1, 5) = Tile1_5
    Tile(1, 6) = Tile1_6

    Tile(2, 0) = Tile2_0
    Tile(2, 1) = Tile2_1
    Tile(2, 2) = Tile2_2
    Tile(2, 3) = Tile2_3
    Tile(2, 4) = Tile2_4
    Tile(2, 5) = Tile2_5
    Tile(2, 6) = Tile2_6

    Tile(3, 0) = Tile3_0
    Tile(3, 1) = Tile3_1
    Tile(3, 2) = Tile3_2
    Tile(3, 3) = Tile3_3
    Tile(3, 4) = Tile3_4
    Tile(3, 5) = Tile3_5
    Tile(3, 6) = Tile3_6

    Tile(4, 0) = Tile4_0
    Tile(4, 1) = Tile4_1
    Tile(4, 2) = Tile4_2
    Tile(4, 3) = Tile4_3
    Tile(4, 4) = Tile4_4
    Tile(4, 5) = Tile4_5
    Tile(4, 6) = Tile4_6

    Tile(5, 0) = Tile5_0
    Tile(5, 1) = Tile5_1
    Tile(5, 2) = Tile5_2
    Tile(5, 3) = Tile5_3
    Tile(5, 4) = Tile5_4
    Tile(5, 5) = Tile5_5
    Tile(5, 6) = Tile5_6

    Tile(6, 1) = Tile6_1
    Tile(6, 2) = Tile6_2
    Tile(6, 3) = Tile6_3
    Tile(6, 4) = Tile6_4
    Tile(6, 5) = Tile6_5

    Call GamePlay(xpos, ypos, KeyValue)
End Sub

Private Sub GamePlay(ByRef xpos As Integer, ByRef ypos As Integer, ByRef KeyValue As Integer)
    Do
        'Sends for answer of the KeyDown event.
        'This is the problem bellow
        KeyValue = _5x5_Board_KeyDown(KeyValue)
        'Decides the position the tile should move to pased on numeric order
        Select Case KeyValue
            'Up
            Case Is = 1
                xpos = xpos - 1
                'Right
            Case Is = 2
                ypos = ypos + 1
                'Down
            Case Is = 3
                xpos = xpos + 1
                'Left
            Case Is = 4
                ypos = ypos - 1
        End Select
        'Colours in the new square on the board of the designated tile
        Tile(xpos, ypos).Load("H:\Computing\Project\TileJump\TileJump\TileJump\Resources\Select1.bmp")
    Loop Until Keys.Escape = True
End Sub

Private Function _5x5_Board_KeyDown(ByRef KeyValue As Integer, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    'This is to declare the key pressed to a numeric value that is used to declare the new position
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        KeyValue = 1
        'MsgBox("KeyValue is " & KeyValue)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        KeyValue = 2
        'MsgBox("KeyValue is " & KeyValue)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        KeyValue = 3
        'MsgBox("KeyValue is " & KeyValue)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        KeyValue = 4
        'MsgBox("KeyValue is " & KeyValue)
    End If
    Return KeyValue
End Function
End Class
```

The above is my code so far. I hope it helps. It may sound really stupid and bad of me, but i've been stuck on this for almost a month

Comment: The way keys are handled in VB.NET differs hugely from the way they are handled in VB6 (much worse in some ways), you'll need to do some research in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KeyDown function accepts three parameters :  keyvalue (which you have), sender as object (type of object), e as eventargs (which key you pressed)

However, when you call the keydown function, you are only passing the first parameter: keyValue

Instead Call the GamePlay() from within the keydown function, instead of the other way around, this way it will return with an integer instead of getting complicated with the sender and eventargs

Comment: Thank you, you have no idea how furstrating this was... As the way programming goes. Past one problem onto the next :D Thanks again!